# preterito imperfecto vs preterito indefinido

Tags: aspecto-gramatical

Mientras estaba leyendo un articulo sobra la Gran Armada de Espana, encontré un frase "Felipe II no podía permanecer impasible ante esos ataques."

Entonces tenía curiosidad y decidí ponerlo en Traductor de Google y lo cambío a 'pudo' en lugar de 'podía'. Estoy confundido porque no hay ningun indicador de que cuando usamos el preterito o imperfecto

hay una razon? hay una estrategía para distinguirlos?

Gracias :)

Comment: Si, recuerdo que en Cou nos lo explicaron. Unas cuestión es cuando se realiza la acción, pasado en este caso, otra la perspectiva del hablante y otra el tiempo actual. Recuerdo que mi libro de texto era de la editorial Anaya, por si quieres buscar referencias. Podía, porque según la perspectiva (tiempo) del hablante puede volver a realizarse, pero recuerdo que con la historia había muchas excepciones

Answer (score 0):

https://onspainschool.com/es/diferencias-entre-preterito-imperfecto-y-perfecto-simple-ejemplos/ aquí te lo explica bien, cuando la acción es continua en el pasado, los ataques duraron un tiempo y mientras (acción continúa) no podía...